# two column with linenumber outer text-area

Tags: revtex, line-numbering

I would like to print the `linenumbers` in the outer-margin. How do get the linenumbers in the `margin` (in this example linenumbers 33 to 63 should be print in `right` column)?

My LaTeX Code is:

```
\RequirePackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{widetext}
$$\alpha + \beta = \gamma$$
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should, first of all, use `revtex4-1` instead of `revtex4` which is a very old implementation of this class.

`revtex4-1` has an option `linenumbers` for that purpose.

Here's your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,linenumbers]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{widetext}
$$\alpha + \beta = \gamma$$
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image]